# Struts OGNL if statement related to action class's variable doesn't work,

Tags: struts2, ognl

The problem is:
Inside my action class, i have one variable:

```
 private String commentAdd = "yes";
```

And the action class goes to reslut.jsp, inside reslut.jsp i have:

```
<s:set name="allowAddComment" value="commentAdd"/>
<s:if test="%{#allowAddComment=='yes'}">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.close();
                    </script>
</s:if>
```

but it doesn't work, can some expert give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

- The property needs to be exposed via a public getter (or in later versions of S2 as a public member, but better to use a getter).
- Why use a string as a boolean? Just use a boolean.
- Why set the property to a different variable? Just use the property.

Are you *sure* this is really what you want? This will close the window as *soon* as that JavaScript is rendered. If that's okay, fine--although if that's the case, why bother rendering the window at all?

Comment: thanks for your advice, i just saw this article:http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/, and guess the jsp can get the variable inside the related action class even the variable is private? But through your comments, seems like the problem is the jsp can't get the private variable. Am i right?

Comment: @user1055108 That page has a getter for the framework property. I don't understand why it uses an additional variable; that's pointless.

Comment: @ Dave Newton yep, that confuse me, too. And in the jsp, they never call the get method, will the get method called by struts?

Comment: @user1055108 You need to read up on how Struts 2 works; in JSP OGNL expressions you reference the property by name. You *may* access it by calling the getter, but there's no reason to.

Comment: @ Dave Newton I know how it works,do i need to do something in the xml, can you give me an example cause my jsp still can't excute the inside js.

Comment: @user1055108 Didn't seem like it, since you asked how it worked. What do you mean, "inside JS"? There's nothing inside JS in what you posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8191/discussion-between-user1055108-and-dave-newton)

Comment: @ Dave Newton My program is working now, but seems like i have to have the s:set to set the variable, if use the action variable directly it won't work.

Comment: @user1055108 If you can't access an action property directly, something else is likely wrong--it should work fine. Consider opening another question, or adding additional info to this one. Glad it's working, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class PageAction extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean addComment;

public boolean isAddComment() {
    return addComment;
}

public void setAddComment(boolean addComment) {
    this.addComment = addComment;
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

```
<s:if test="%{addComment}">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.close();
 </script>
</s:if>
```

Comment: where will i excute the isAddComment()  method. And should <s:if test="%{addComment}">
add a #:  <s:if test="%{#addComment}">?